# unexpected T_FUNCTION error

Tags: php, error-handling

I am using this function

```
    usort($arr, function($a, $b) use ($str) {return (strpos($a, $str) - strpos($b, $str));});
```

to sort the array `$arr`. This function works fine on localhost however when I uploaded my site online this error comes up

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like your PHP version on your host is < 5.3.0
and its not support anonymous functions

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

you may try this

```
function cmp($a, $b, $str) {
    return (strpos($a, $str) - strpos($b, $str));
}

usort($arr, create_function('$a, $b', 'return cmp($a, $b, "' . $str . '");'));
```

or upgrade you php on server.

Comment: The answer you suggested works fine but what do you mean by upgrade the php on server. Can I upgrade the server or my hosting account if I don't own the server?

Comment: if you use hosting, you can only ask for that a hoster. in 99% they will not do that. you can change your hoster

Comment: I would highly recommend changing your host if they only offer a version of PHP which has not been supported since the 6th of Janurary **2011** (PHP 5.2)

Comment: Most shared hosting providers actually support switching (e.g. SetHandler) between multiple PHP versions (in particular for FPM or suphp setups). It's just that the older is commonly default.